# Writing linear and exponential equations for fitted SMA model

Tags: r, math

I have fitted a standard major axis model to my data, and I need add an equation onto the plot but I can't figure out what this should be.

My data looks like this:

```
> head(d1)
       x                   y
1      5.379431            10.263158
2      5.863559            5.287081
3     10.367855            4.186603
4     11.459073            5.669856
5     14.477543            6.387560
6     16.713999            4.377990
```

My model gives the following:

```
library(smatr)
m1 <- sma(y~x, data = d1, log="xy")
#Coefficients:
#             elevation     slope
#estimate    -0.23978063 0.8576100
#lower limit -0.54266508 0.6786154
#upper limit  0.06310381 1.0838170
#H0 : variables uncorrelated
#R-squared : 0.3228417 
#P-value : 1.3667e-05
```

So based on this I have plotted the data and added an equation for the line that looks like this:
[plot1 of data and SMA fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJu5z.png)

My problem is that the regression equation y=-0.240+0.858x doesn't make sense with the trendline. I have also been asked to provide an exponential equation (e.g. y = ab^x) and I have no idea how to convert it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If `log(y)=k*log(x)`, then exponentiation on both sides will lead to `y=e^{klog(x)}=(e^k)*x`, which is of course in the `y=a+bx` format.

Comment: Sorry! I realised that what I had written was incorrect. The formula that does work is: y=e^(-0.240 + (0.858*log10(x)) or y=e^(a+(b*log10(x))

Comment: I guess you missed a bracket at the end

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, the working formula is: `y=e^(0.240+ 0.858*log10(x)))`.

This is directly in the `y=a+bx` format, with:

`a=e^0.240`

`b=e^(0.858/ln(10))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. This formula doesn't seem to return the correct fitted values, however.